# unsupported dynamic reloc r_arm_rel32 error linking ACE static library on NDK19

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, ace

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to port a legacy application from NDK 16 to NDK 19.  The problem is that this application was built in top of ACE C++ library, that is linked as a static lib using static library import on CMakeLists.txt file.

The CMakeLists file is configure in the same way of https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt example:

```
add_library(lib_ace STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_ace PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${distribution_DIR}/libACE.a)
```

Ant then

```
target_link_libraries(myProjectLib
                  android
                  lib_ace
                  ... many other libs ...
                  log)
```

http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/ACE-INSTALL.html#android

I created the standalone toolchain and the ACE library builds without error, following the instructions on ACE website on the given link.

But when I try to link the ACE Static library to my projects jni C++ dynamic library on Android Studio,  the ninja-build complains: "unsupported dynamic reloc r_arm_rel32"

If someone knows about any current open source project or example using both ACE and Android, please provide a link!
I appreciate  any help!!!

Comment: Have you searched already the web for this error, for example have you tried https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/191

Comment: Yes I did. On previous NDKs we could use gcc. But on NDK19, I'm having the same issue as  lamnguyen95 on the [link](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/191#issuecomment-466956127) that you provided